# Trying to find a formula or value that represents the rate at which something is increasing [Context: Game Design]

Tags: statistics, derivatives, exponential-function

I am designing a game in which a player recruits specific units to their army. These units have a cost associated with them. This cost is determined by the stats of the unit *(I'm using the phrase "stats" as a reflection of the numbers that affect the unit's in-game performance. For example, the number of hits they can take before being taken off the board or Wounds .)*

Different stats have different rates of increase as their more impactful to the unit's prowess on the battlefield.

My goal is to be able to measure and amend the following values in order the balance and finetune the design as the game evolves. Those values are:

1. The rate at which the cost of a stat increases
2. The cost of the lowest possible value for a stat
3. The cost of the highest possible value for a stat

Is there a formula that I can utilize where when I plug it into excel I can manage a "stat table" with just these values?

I thought I could utilize y=mb+b and manipulate from there, however, this doesn't really account for an exponential curve. For example, the cost of a weapon's range increases exponentially as the range increases.

I also thought I could just add a graph for each stat line to visually see the stat line and just manually adjust it. but this has been incredibly arduous. Plus loading a bunch of small graphs has made my clean spreadsheet far too clunky.

I've tried looking at derivatives but it doesn't look like they can be deployed in excel well?

Clarity would be so great!

Comment: You could play with graphs of $a^x$ in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). of special interest may be when $a>1$ and when $a<1$.